# Nodejs how to create a `data tree` on result

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to fix or redesign results or create a TreeView after mapping the result using nodejs?
this is my code, please check below the desired result

```
const getquestionnaire = await QuestionnaireModels.getQuestion(yearlevel, section);
res.send(getquestionnaire);
```

getQuestion

```
async getQuestion(yearlevel, section) {
    let student = await Database.getConnection().models.student;
    let qgroup = await Database.getConnection().models.questiongroups;
    let qdetails = await Database.getConnection().models.questiondetails;
    let oitem = await Database.getConnection().models.optionitems;
    student.hasMany(qgroup, { foreignKey: '_id'});
    student.hasMany(qdetails, {foreignKey: 'QuestionGroupID'})
    student.hasMany(oitem, {foreignKey: 'QuestionDetailsID'})
    let question = await Database.getConnection().models.student.findAll({
     attributes:[
    'yearlevel','section','questiongroups.GroupName','questiondetails.QuestionDescription','optionitems.OptionDescription'
    ],
      where: {
        yearlevel: yearlevel,
        section: section
      },
      include:[
        { model: qgroup, attribute:[] },
        { model: qdetails, attribute:[] },
        { model: oitem, attribute:[] },
    ],
      raw: true,
    })
    return result
  },
```

current result

```
{
    "yearlevel": "Grade 7",
    "section": "Apple",
    "Groupname": "Third",
    "QuestionDescription":"Eating Disorder",
    "OptionDescription": "Test"
        
},
{
    "yearlevel": "Grade 8",
    "section": "Blue",
    "Groupname": "Test Group name",
    "QuestionDescription":"Test Question",
    "OptionDescription": "Test"
        
}
```

desired result

```
[
    {
        "yearlevel": "Grade 7",
        "section": "Apple",
        "question":{
            "Groupname": "Third",
            "groupdetail":{
                "QuestionDescription":"Eating Disorder",
                "optionItems":{
                    "OptionDescription": "Test"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "yearlevel": "Grade 8",
        "section": "Blue",
        "question":{
            "Groupname": "Test Group name",
            "groupdetail":{
                "QuestionDescription":"Test Question",
                "optionItems":{
                    "OptionDescription": "Test"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

> dont mind this message dont mind this message dont mind this message
> dont mind this message dont mind this message dont mind this message
> dont mind this message dont mind this message dont mind this message

Comment: you would need to format the data to the specified json format that you need,by iterating over the result that you recieve

Comment: @SwarupChavan how to format?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const currentResult = [{
   "yearlevel": "Grade 7",
   "section": "Apple",
   "Groupname": "Third",
   "QuestionDescription": "Eating Disorder",
   "OptionDescription": "Test"

},
{
   "yearlevel": "Grade 8",
   "section": "Blue",
   "Groupname": "Test Group name",
   "QuestionDescription": "Test Question",
   "OptionDescription": "Test"

}];

const desiredResult = currentResult.map(({ yearlevel, section, Groupname, QuestionDescription, OptionDescription }) => ({
   yearlevel,
   section,
   question: {
      Groupname,
      groupdetails: {
         QuestionDescription,
         optionItems: {
            OptionDescription
         }
      }
   }
}))
```