# Nodejs how to create a `data tree` with array on result

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to fix or redesign results or create a TreeView after mapping the result using nodejs?
this is my code, please check below the desired result

What I want here is that if the QuestionGroupID is existing it will not create another row but it will create array on `optionItems`

please see the desired result vs current result to understand what i mean

```
const getquestionnaire = await QuestionnaireModels.getQuestion(yearlevel, section);
const desiredResult = currentResult.map(({ yearlevel, section, Groupname, _id, QuestionDescription, OptionDescription }) => ({
   yearlevel,
   section,
   question: {
      Groupname,
      groupdetails: {
         QuestionGroupID,
         QuestionDescription,
         optionItems: {
            OptionDescription
         }
      }
   }
}))
res.send(getquestionnaire);
```

getQuestion

```
async getQuestion(yearlevel, section) {
    let student = await Database.getConnection().models.student;
    let qgroup = await Database.getConnection().models.questiongroups;
    let qdetails = await Database.getConnection().models.questiondetails;
    let oitem = await Database.getConnection().models.optionitems;
    student.hasMany(qgroup, { foreignKey: '_id'});
    student.hasMany(qdetails, {foreignKey: 'QuestionGroupID'});
    let question = await Database.getConnection().models.student.findAll({
     attributes:[
    'yearlevel','section','questiondetails.QuestionGroupID','questiongroups.GroupName','questiondetails.QuestionDescription','optionitems.OptionDescription'
    ],
      where: {
        yearlevel: yearlevel,
        section: section
      },
      include:[
        { model: qgroup, attribute:[] },
        { model: qdetails, attribute:[] },
    ],
      raw: true,
    })
    return result
  },
  let org_data = question.map(async data => {
        let item = await oitem.findAll({
            attributes: ['OptionDescription'],
            where: {QuestionDetailsID: data.QuestionGroupID},
            raw: true
        })
        
        return  item
    })
```

current result

```
[
    {
        "yearlevel": "Grade 7",
        "section": "Apple",
        "question":{
            "Groupname": "Third",
            "groupdetail":{
                "QuestionGroupID": 1,
                "QuestionDescription":"Eating Disorder",
                "optionItems":{
                    "OptionDescription": "Test 1"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "yearlevel": "Grade 7",
        "section": "Orange",
        "question":{
            "Groupname": "Third",
            "groupdetail":{
                "QuestionGroupID": 1,
                "QuestionDescription":"Eating Disorder",
                "optionItems":{
                    "OptionDescription": "Test 2"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "yearlevel": "Grade 8",
        "section": "Blue",
        "question":{
            "Groupname": "Test Group name",
            "groupdetail":{
                "QuestionGroupID": 2,
                "QuestionDescription":"Test Question",
                "optionItems":{
                    "OptionDescription": "Test"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

desired result

```
[
    {
        "yearlevel": "Grade 7",
        "section": "Apple",
        "question":{
            "Groupname": "Third",
            "groupdetail":{
                "QuestionGroupID": 1,
                "QuestionDescription":"Eating Disorder",
                "optionItems":[
                    {
                        "OptionDescription": "Test 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "OptionDescription": "Test 2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },

    {
        "yearlevel": "Grade 8",
        "section": "Blue",
        "question":{
            "Groupname": "Test Group name",
            "groupdetail":{
                "QuestionGroupID": 2,
                "QuestionDescription":"Test Question",
                "optionItems":{
                    "OptionDescription": "Test"
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

this is related on this [Nodejs how to create a `data tree` on result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73687555/nodejs-how-to-create-a-data-tree-on-result) but different problem

> dont mind this message dont mind this message dont mind this message
> dont mind this message dont mind this message dont mind this message
> dont mind this message dont mind this message dont mind this message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple case of "group array of objects by key using reduce". After we group by the `QuestionGroupID`, we take the values of that array and construct for each of grouped arrays the required item with the inner array of `optionItems`.

```js
var input = [{yearlevel:"Grade 7",section:"Apple",question:{Groupname:"Third",groupdetail:{QuestionGroupID:1,QuestionDescription:"Eating Disorder",optionItems:{OptionDescription:"Test 1"}}}},{yearlevel:"Grade 7",section:"Orange",question:{Groupname:"Third",groupdetail:{QuestionGroupID:1,QuestionDescription:"Eating Disorder",optionItems:{OptionDescription:"Test 2"}}}},{yearlevel:"Grade 8",section:"Blue",question:{Groupname:"Test Group name",groupdetail:{QuestionGroupID:2,QuestionDescription:"Test Question",optionItems:{OptionDescription:"Test"}}}}];

var result = Object.values(input.reduce(function (agg, item) {
  agg[item.question.groupdetail.QuestionGroupID] ??= [];
  agg[item.question.groupdetail.QuestionGroupID].push(item)
  return agg;
}, {})).map(function(arr) {
  var result_item = arr[arr.length-1]
  var optionItems = arr.reduce(function(agg, item) {
    agg.push(item.question.groupdetail.optionItems)
    return agg;
  }, [])
  result_item.question.groupdetail.optionItems = optionItems;
  return result_item;
})

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Comment: the array is optionItems not the groupdetail @IT goldman

Comment: I dont know why from this line i cant push `agg[item.question.groupdetail.QuestionGroupID].push(item)`

Comment: can you remake your code that the array is the optionitem not groupdetails

Comment: I just did I think

Comment: from   agg[item.question.groupdetail.QuestionGroupID] ??= [];
  agg[item.question.groupdetail.QuestionGroupID].push(item) what does it mean?

Comment: Something like `agg[x] = agg[x] || []` it's called nullish coalescing